# what is the difference between any and * in flow?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I have read [flowtype](https://flowtype.org/) documentation and I cannot be sure about.

Is there any difference between the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*` tells Flow to infer a type parameter. To my knowledge, it can only be used for type parameters (e.g. `Array<*>`). It will always either infer a valid type for that position, or give you an error.

However, [`any`](https://flowtype.org/docs/quick-reference.html#any) is an unsafe type. It can be used to circumvent the typechecker. You can assign anything to a variable typed as `any`, and you can also assign it to anything.